Drag BottomSheet in BottomSheetScaffold by the box
I can’t drag the bottom page by green box element
Globals vars
val CONST_UI_PANEL_FINDER_HEIGHT = 40
var CONST_UI_PANEL_DRAG_WIDTH = 100
var CONST_UI_PANEL_SHEET_COLLAPSED = CONST_UI_PANEL_CALENDAR_HEIGHT + CONST_UI_PANEL_FINDER_HEIGHT
var CONST_UI_PANEL_SHEET_HALF = 400
var CONST_UI_PANEL_SHEET_FULL = 800

var PEEK_HEIGHT = mutableIntStateOf(CONST_UI_PANEL_SHEET_COLLAPSED)

code in module
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun PanelContentBar() {

    val bottomSheetSt = rememberStandardBottomSheetState(
        skipHiddenState = true,
        initialValue = SheetValue.PartiallyExpanded
    )
    val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(bottomSheetSt)

    BottomSheetScaffold(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(color = JetMainTheme.colors.background),
        sheetContent = {
            Footer()
        },
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        sheetPeekHeight = PEEK_HEIGHT.value.dp,
        sheetContainerColor = JetMainTheme.colors.background,
        sheetDragHandle = {
            Finder(scaffoldState)
        },
        sheetSwipeEnabled = false
    ) {
    }

}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Finder(stateBt: BottomSheetScaffoldState) {

    Box (
        contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart,
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(CONST_UI_PANEL_FINDER_HEIGHT.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(
                start = CONST_UI_OTSTUP_X2.dp,
                end = (CONST_UI_PANEL_DRAG_WIDTH + CONST_UI_OTSTUP_X2 * 2).dp
            ),
    ) {
        val message = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
        BasicTextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(CONST_UI_OTSTUP.dp))
                .border(1.dp, color = JetMainTheme.colors.primary)
                .fillMaxWidth()
            //.padding(CONST_UI_OTSTUP_MIN.dp)
            ,
            singleLine = true,
            value = message.value,
            onValueChange = { newText -> message.value = newText },
        )
    }

    Box (
        contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterEnd,
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(CONST_UI_PANEL_FINDER_HEIGHT.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(end = CONST_UI_OTSTUP_X2.dp),
    ) {
        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        var expandedType by remember {
            mutableStateOf(ExpandedType.COLLAPSED)
        }
        var isUpdated = false
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(
                    color = JetMainTheme.colors.primary,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(CONST_UI_OTSTUP_MIN.dp)
                )
                .height(CONST_UI_OTSTUP.dp)
                .width(CONST_UI_PANEL_DRAG_WIDTH.dp)
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectVerticalDragGestures(
                        onVerticalDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                            change.consume()
                            if (!isUpdated) {
                                Log.i(
                                    "UIPanelContent.Finder",
                                    "vert drag: dragAmount=$dragAmount  expandedType=${expandedType}  peekHaight=${PEEK_HEIGHT.value}"
                                )
                                expandedType = when {
                                    dragAmount < 0 && expandedType == ExpandedType.COLLAPSED -> ExpandedType.HALF
                                    dragAmount < 0 && expandedType == ExpandedType.HALF -> ExpandedType.FULL
                                    dragAmount > 0 && expandedType == ExpandedType.FULL -> ExpandedType.HALF
                                    dragAmount > 0 && expandedType == ExpandedType.HALF -> ExpandedType.COLLAPSED
                                    else -> expandedType
                                }
                                isUpdated = true
                            }
                        },
                        onDragEnd = {
                            isUpdated = false
                            PEEK_HEIGHT.value = when {
                                expandedType == ExpandedType.HALF -> CONST_UI_PANEL_SHEET_HALF
                                expandedType == ExpandedType.FULL -> CONST_UI_PANEL_SHEET_FULL
                                else -> CONST_UI_PANEL_SHEET_COLLAPSED
                            }
                            Log.i(
                                "UIPanelContent.Finder",
                                "onDragEnd: expandedType=${expandedType}  peekHeight=${PEEK_HEIGHT.value}"
                            )
                            scope.launch {
                                stateBt.bottomSheetState.partialExpand()
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
                ,
        ) {
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Footer() {
    Column (
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(color = androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color.Blue)
            .padding(bottom = CONST_UI_PANEL_CALENDAR_HEIGHT.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()

    ) {
        Text("line 1 text")
        Text("line 2 text")
        Text("line 3 text")
        Text("line 4 text")
    }
}

//--

enum class ExpandedType {
    HALF, FULL, COLLAPSED
}


Initially, when I launch the application I have this screen
screen1
Then when I swipe vertically, nothing happens
(the bottom sheet should have opened halfway)
After swiping again, the bottom sheet opens completely.
screen2
Next, when I swipe down, the bottom sheet should go down half the screen, but it decreases from the bottom
screen3
When you swipe down again, the bottom sheet collapses as in the first picture
